# Emulate "MATLAB-like" exponential ticks in tikz visualization

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-datavisualization

I am trying to include some plots in my LaTeX document using the data visualization library of TikZ, but I am not satisfied with the number format of the axis ticks for high values:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{"datafile.txt"}
0,   0.5e6
1,   1e6
2,   1.3e6

\end{filecontents*}

\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization[%
        scientific axes,
        visualize as line,
        y axis={label=y label},
        ]
        data [read from file="datafile.txt", headline={x, y}];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

produces 
[image]

I would really prefer a more brief approach like it is done in figures produced by matlab:
[image]

Is there any way to achieve this behavior (common exponent at the top of the axis) via the data visualization library? I have already tried adjusting the typesetter, but the values are too high to manipulate them manually and then I would still have to create the additional exponent tick, although I could also settle for including the scaling in the axis label.

Comment: You are using tikz rather than pgfplots, is there any reason behind?

Comment: Given the size of the numbers, you might need to pre-process the data file to avoid exceeding TeX's limits.

Comment: @mirkom : The only reason being that I already started with tikz data visualization and already spent some hours on coming up with a syntax that suits my case. Originally knowing neither, I assumed the tikz-internal way would be less cumbersome, which appears to be wrong. I actually already tested the matlab2tikz script, which uses pgfplots, and it looks quite alright. However, I think I prefer the default look of the tikz ploting tools, provided, it was possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a rather hard one.

What we basically want, is to set the mantissa of the numbers in the labels as fixed numbers after they have been scaled to a maximum exponent. Therefore I define a macro `\newcommand{\maxE}{6}`. Then I define my typesetter, where I use as overall option for number formatting `\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=1}`. The precision sets here the number of digits shown after the period. Higher numbers for the precision should be used with care due to possible rounding errors. With `\pgfmathfloatparsenumber{#1}` I am passing the argument given by the datavizualition to my code. Afterwards I pass with `\pgfmathfloattomacro{\pgfmathresult}{\F}{\M}{\E}` the flag, mantissa and exponent to my predefined macros, to make use of these numbers. Then I calculate the scaled exponent by `\renewcommand{\newE}{\E-\maxE}` and scale the number which shall be printed to the label `\pgfmathparse{\M*pow(10,\newE)}`. Afterwards `\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}` is printing the number. At the end of the datavisualization finally `info{ \node [above right, style={font={\footnotesize}}] at (data visualization bounding box.north west) {$\times10^\maxE$};}` prints the label, outlining to which exponent the axis is scaled.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}
\usepackage{filecontents}
%
\begin{filecontents*}{"datafile.txt"}
0,   0.5e6
1,   1e6
2,   1.3e6
\end{filecontents*}
%
% defining the macros to which we need to pass the variables in recalculating the tick labels
\newcommand{\F}{0}
\newcommand{\M}{1}
\newcommand{\E}{0}
\newcommand{\maxE}{6} % setting the exponent to which the labels should be scaled
\newcommand{\newE}{0}
%
% defining my typesetter
\makeatletter
\def\mytypesetter#1{%
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=1} % The overall number formatting of the labels
    \pgfmathfloatparsenumber{#1} % parsing the numbers to the code
    \pgfmathfloattomacro{\pgfmathresult}{\F}{\M}{\E} % passing flag, mantissa and exponent of the number to the predefined macros
    \renewcommand{\newE}{\E-\maxE} % calculating the scaled exponent
    \pgfmathparse{\M*pow(10,\newE)} % calculating the scaled number to print at the label
    \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult} % printing the number
}
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \datavisualization[%
        scientific axes,
        visualize as line,
        y axis={
                label=y label,
                ticks={tick typesetter/.code=\mytypesetter{##1}} % passing the typesetting of the labels to my defined setter
                }
        ]
        data [read from file="datafile.txt", headline={x, y}]
        info{
            \node [above right, style={font={\footnotesize}}]
            at (data visualization bounding box.north west) {$\times10^\maxE$};
            }
        ;
%
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I have been fumbling around with these parsing macros, but it would have probably taken me some more days until I came up with something working...;)

Comment: One little thing though: Would you know of any way to adjust the space between the axis label and the tick labels? Since it still has the size providing for the full exponential tick labels .

Comment: Try to set `label={[node style={below=-0.5em}] {y label}}`. By adjusting the number you can place the label according to your needs.